# How to mail a googlesheet chart through script editor?

Tags: html, google-apps-script

The Code that I am using is sending mail (pdf) directly to recipient correctly.
what I want is only the chart part to be there in the pdf or only the range that contain something (data).
This code is fetching whole sheet as pdf, even the unused cells.
How to fetch the sheet (pdf) without unused cells?

```
function onOpen()
{
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  ui.createMenu('Email').addItem('Send Emails', 'sendEmails').addToUi();
}  
function sendEmails(){ 
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sh4 = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");

  if(true){
  var emailBody="Dear Parent,<br>  <br>Please find the Program chart of your child.<br> To discuss it further, the Engagement  Manager would call you shortly.<br> ";
  var file= DriveApp.getFileById('<spreadsheet-id>');

  var currentEmail1 = sh4.getRange(1, 4).getValues();

      MailApp.sendEmail({
    to:'email-address',
    subject: "Wizklub Hots program",
    htmlBody: emailBody,
     attachments:[file.getAs(MimeType.PDF).setName('student report' + '.pdf')]
    });
} 
}
```

Comment: [`getCharts()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getcharts) first?

Answer (score 0):

```
attachments:[file.getBlob().getAs(MimeType.PDF).setName('student report' + '.pdf')]
```

Comment: Tried this to , but the result is same as mine.It is projecting whole sheet .I want only the chart part to be sent as pdf or chart as a image

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer . Good luck 

Answer (score 0):

#### Answer:

*You need to collect the charts from the sheet first, then send as an email attachment with the correct Mimetype Enum.*

#### Code changes:

Firstly you need to gather the charts from the sheets:

```js
var chart = sh4.getCharts()[0];
```

And then send this as an attachment with a compatible Mimetype - one of an image so either `JPEG` or `PNG`:

```js
attachments:[chart.getAs(MimeType.PNG).setName('student report' + '.png')]
```

or:

```js
attachments:[chart.getAs('image/png').setName('student report' + '.png')]
```

Remember that `getCharts()` will return all charts in the sheet so you need to send the correct one by referencing the corresponding array element.

#### References:

- [Google Sheets API v4 - Charts](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/samples/charts)
- [Google Apps Script - method `getCharts()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getcharts)
- [Google Apps Script - Class `EmbeddedChart`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/embedded-chart.html)
- [Google Apps Script - Enum MimeType](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/mime-type)

Comment: TypeError: Cannot find function getAs in object EmbeddedChart.

Comment: [`getAs(contentType)` is a method of `EmbeddedChart` according to the documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/embedded-chart.html#getAs(String)). You can also try using a PNG format or specifying the MimeType as a string rather than an Enum. I have updated my answer.